# How to add a product category to an Open ERP database?

Tags: odoo

I'm migrating an `OpenERP` database and one of my modules fails to load its data (product) because it refers to an existing Product Category `Services`, which does not exist on the target database.

I searched and found a `Services` category defined by the `product` module *demo data*, but I think that loading demo data is a bad idea.

How do I create a `Services` product category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your module is referencing the product category. If it's searching by name, then just create a new product category with the right name. In version 6.0, the product categories are configured under `Sales: Configuration: Product: Product Categories`.

More likely is that your module includes an XML data file that refers to the product category by its import id. Those are usually set up during a module import, but you could create one yourself. You can edit import ids under `Administration: Configuration: Sequences: Object Identifiers`.

If you are building the module yourself, consider including the `Services` product category in your module the same way you're including the other data.

Comment: I'm migrating a module. Data is in a CSV file and references "Services" by name, it's not an XML id...